# What does the "verbosity" parameter of a random forest mean? (sklearn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

One of the kwargs for building a random forest in sklearn is ["verbose"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html). The documentation says that it

```
Controls the verbosity of the tree building process
```

After searching online I am still not sure what this means.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Verbosity in keyword arguments usually means showing more 'wordy' information for the task.

In this case, for machine learning, by setting verbose to a higher number (`2` vs `1`), you may see more information about the tree building process.

Seeing the verbosity settings for [another machine learning application](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/ml/dtrees/c4.5/verbrules.html) may help to understand the principle.

Comment: It is an integer, not a bool. What would the difference between verbose=1 and verbose=2?

Comment: updated the answer to distinguish. Usually, a higher number will show more info

Comment: I am also wondering what kind of information will be shown if verbose is set `1` or `2`. Can anyone upload a screenshot?

Answer (score 19):

In case of `verbose=1` you get only the red logs (pretty rare in big models) with elapsed time, but changing verbose to 2 prints you the rest of information about building each tree:

[image]